# What is >> operator in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, colors, operators

I am sure this has to as sweet and plain as butter. But I am not able get it or even find it.

It is related to colours in .net. I have taken a sample code from internet and trying to understand it. It takes a `uInt` as argument and do something to return `a`, `r`, `g` and `b` byte values. The method goes as:

```
private Color UIntToColor(uint color)
{
    byte a = (byte)(color >> 24);
    byte r = (byte)(color >> 16);
    byte g = (byte)(color >> 8);
    byte b = (byte)(color >> 0);
    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}
```

so what is `>>` here. For example,

```
color = 4278190335 // (blue color)
```

After processing

```
a = 255
r = 0
g = 0
b = 255
```

So can anyone help me to understand this?

Comment: You can look it up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: And more specifically http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's right-shift operator.

Basically, what it does is that it shifts all bits of the first operand to the right. The second operand specifies how "far" are bits shifted. For example:

```
uint value = 240; // this can be represented as 11110000
uint shift2 = value >> 2; // shift2 now equals 00111100
uint shift4 = value >> 4; // shift4 now equals 00001111
```

Good article on the subject is [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpShiftOperators.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

[It's in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[Right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So, if you convert your value of 4278190335 to hex (because it's easier to see what's going on) you get 0xFF0000FF

So this line:

```
byte a = (byte)(color >> 24);
```

Will shift 0xFF0000FF 24 bits to the right to give you 0x000000FF. If you cast that to a byte, you will truncate off the most significant bits and end up with 0xFF or 255.

So you should be able to figure out what the other 3 lines do.

Comment: Rather than just linking, a good answer should also include the name of the operator. It's good to be able to learn without having to navigate off-page.

Comment: In general it is easier to see what is going on not in HEX but in binary format - `1010101` since you are shifting bits ;)But surely when shifting by `8*n` bits it makes sense looking into HEX since you are shifting bytes

Comment: @sil: Yes, but I'm not going to write out 4278190335 in binary.

Answer (score 4):

>> is the shift-right operator.

Comment: thanks for the name Shift right operator. I did the rest of hardwork +1

Comment: oops...mis typed in excitement...sorry